# Allow minus symbol (-) in value-bound react inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wondering if there is an elegant and/or recommended solution to this problem.

If I have an input which I'm using for numbers, and I'd like to enter a negative number, I first have to enter the `-` symbol. When I enter this, `parseInt` will return `NaN`, which is understandable. However, if the value of the input is bound to the result of the `parseInt`, then I can never finish entering the number, as it will fail as soon as it attempts to parse the `-` as an int.

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')
  
  const update = ({ target }) => {
    const { value } = target;
    
    const attemptedParse = parseInt(value);
    
    if (!attemptedParse) {
      setInputValue(value);
      setCount(0);
    } else {
      setInputValue(attemptedParse);
      setCount(attemptedParse);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <input value={inputValue} onChange={update} />
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The above solution **uses two separate states**, one for the input, and another for the actual value. But this seems a little messy, and I wonder if anyone has any solutions which involve a little less code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be two states, one for input value, another one for parsed integer.

Input value shouldn't necessarily re-set to parsed integer, this may make input more troublesome, like in the case of negative number:

```
  const update = ({ target }) => {
    const { value } = target;

    const attemptedParse = parseInt(value);

    if (!Object.is(NaN, attemptedParse)) {
      setCount(attemptedParse);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression

```js
const { useState } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')
  
  const update = ({ target }) => {
    var { value } = target;
    
    // Replace all non-numeric characters to ''
    value = value.replace(/[^0-9-]+/g, '');
    
    // The real pattern you are looking for
    var pattern = /([-])?([0-9]+)/g;
    var matches = value.match(pattern);
    if(matches){
      value = matches[0];
    }
    setInputValue(value);
    setCount(value);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <input value={inputValue} onChange={update} />
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```